# How to wrap ECS components to OOP in libgdx ashley?

Tags: java, libgdx

Currently I am using [builder-pattern](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjAudG17PnNAhUBp5QKHUIpBqMQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBuilder_pattern&usg=AFQjCNEI1lW-EEc2OTaQM-G2qG5atOhxVA&sig2=u3FEjDEPJjBtD6NfwX3Xcw) to create my `Entities`

```
PooledEngine engine = new PooledEngine();

...

CharacterComponent character = engine.createComponent(CharacterComponent.class);
TextureComponent texture = engine.createComponent(TextureComponent.class);
SizeComponent size = engine.createComponent(SizeComponent.class);
TransformComponent transform = engine.createComponent(TransformComponent.class);
PhysicsComponent physics = engine.createComponent(PhysicsComponent.class);

Entity entity = engine.createEntity();
entity.flag = Constants.CHARACTER;

entity.add(character);
entity.add(texture);
entity.add(size);
entity.add(transform);
entity.add(physics);

engine.addEntity(entity);
```

Because `PooledEngine` class didnt support the creation of casting an Entity to another class that extends Entity. Example `engine.createEntity(Character.class);`, I am having hard thinking how do I wrap these components into single class.

**Objectives**

```
class interface ICharacter {
    void attack();
}

class interface IMoveable {
    void move();
}

class Character extends Entity implements ICharacter, IMoveable {

    private Body body;
    private Vector2 position;

    public Character() {
        PhysicsComponent physics = Mappers.physics.get(this);
        TransformComponent transform = Mappers.transform.get(this);

        body = physics.body;
        position = transform.position;
    }

    @Override
    public void attack() {

    }

    @Override
    public void move() {
        ...
        position.add(x, y);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are totally defeating the purpose of using an Entity-Component-System by creating that Character class. The whole drive behind ECS architecture is the decoupling/separation of data(Components) and logic(Systems). 
What you need to do is create separate Systems to handle attack and movement logic.

Read these two articles, they'll help you get a better understanding of ECS architecture and how to use it:

[**What is an entity system framework for game development?**](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/what-is-an-entity-framework)

[**Why use an entity system framework for game development?**](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/why-use-an-entity-framework)